# Why is this act supposed to be a final success for the future antagonists?

Tags: time-travel, tenet

(All-spoiler question)

In the 2020 film *Tenet*, arms dealer Sator is instructed to bury the "algorithm" by means of a cave-in at Stalsk-12, and his success in doing this somehow ensures success for the future baddies who want to invert time/the world/entropy.

I don't quite understand why that is. Why can't people who oppose them just organize an excavation of the place? I mean, sure, there's a lot of dirt, but not more than your typical mine... and one would not even have to mine through stone, just clear rubble and dirt. So couldn't the Tenet organization just retrieve the "algorithm" again?

Answer (score 2):

He wasn't simply burying it.

The algorithm was a weapon that he was supposed to be setting off. The nuclear explosion that happens in the Hypocenter was supposed to somehow trigger the algorithm so that it would reverse entropy completely and cause the universal reversal of time (as opposed to the localised reversals we see via the use of the turnstiles earlier in the movie).

Of course, there's a question of whether this would be a success for the antagonists who provided the instructions and the means for Sator to begin collecting the algorithm. Reversing time and destroying humanity at that moment may or may not also destroy the future antagonists via something akin to the [grandfather paradox](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grandfather_paradox) - but as Neil explains "it doesn't really matter" - they believe they will survive.

Comment: Sator wasn't attempting to trigger the algorithm. He was sending it to the future. The people in the future are expecting Sator to send them the location of the assembled algorithm (inside the capsule / dead drop), so they could get it in the future and trigger it then. If Sator was meant to trigger the algorithm himself, in his present, there would be no need for him to reveal the location of the dead drop to the people in the future. See [Why didn't the algorithm detonate when Kat killed Sator?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/112247/1006) for more information about this.

Answer (score 0):

##### Once the algorithm is buried/sealed and its location sent to the future antagonists (posterity), then posterity will have the algorithm and will use it to destroy everyone in the present. Since everyone in the present is destroyed, retrieving it later is no longer possible.

The reason why the plan of the people in the future (hereby referred to as "posterity") depends on Sator burying the algorithm at Stalsk-12 is because of how dead drops work in *Tenet*. Dead drops are how objects are sent from the present to the future. The sender buries the object in a secure and sealed location and sends the coordinates to the receiver. The receiver then digs up the object in their own time.

Here is a dialogue from *Tenet – The Complete Screenplay* that explains this (emphasis mine):

> **PROTAGONIST:** Dead drops. **He buries his time capsule, transmits the location**, then digs it up to collect whatever inverted material they’ve sent.
> **NEIL:** **Instantaneous.** Where’s he bury it?

The key word here is “instantaneous”. From Sator’s perspective, as soon as he buries the object successfully and sends the location, posterity has it in their possession. And he gets posterity’s response (the inverted materials) right away. (This may seem paradoxical, but as Ives says, “Do not get on the chopper if you can’t stop thinking in linear terms.””)

Sator’s final mission, given by posterity, is to bury the algorithm, which is the key to inverting the entropy of the world, in a dead drop at the Stalsk-12 bomb explosion hypocenter, and transmit its location to posterity. (The time bomb in the cavern is not meant to trigger the algorithm, but to cause a massive cave-in and seal the algorithm underground.)

The Tenet team has two objectives and *only* two objectives: 1. to stop Sator from killing himself and sending the location, and 2. to lift the algorithm before it gets buried. They fail the first one but succeed in the second one. This is crucial because once the algorithm is buried and the location is sent, posterity has it instantaneously from the present’s point of view. There is neither time nor opportunity to dig it up later, because by then, posterity would have already used it to invert the entropy of the world and destroy everyone in the present. As Neil puts it, it would be “end of play”.

> **PROTAGONIST:** **That explosion *seals up the algorithm*.**
> **IVES:** Then we’d better **pull it out of that hole *before* the bomb goes off**.

> **PROTAGONIST:** It always counts. You’re not there to kill him – you’re the backstop. **If we haven’t lifted that algorithm and he kills himself, he takes us all with him, *instantly***.

- *Tenet – The Complete Screenplay* (emphasis mine)

Notice how in the dialogue, the words “before”, “instantaneous”, and “instantly” emphasize the urgency and the stakes of the situation, and how the Protagonist said that they would all be destroyed “instantly” rather than “if plan A fails [assuming that we won’t be destroyed **instantly**], plan B is to dig it out later”. **If they fail to lift the algorithm, the effect is instant (the destruction of everyone in the present), so there is no more “after”.**

Comment: Hmm. I think the concept of *seemingly* instantaneous is not quite what you mean. The item doesn't magically appear, it still needs to be hidden and travel backwards in time, making it potentially interceptible.

Comment: @Valorum My interpretation of that dialogue is that Sator buries a dead drop, transmits the location, and immediately retrieves it with the inverted materials from the future. This meant that as soon as he buries a dead drop and sends the location, the future replies instantly, so Sator doesn’t have to wait for some time (in which case the dead drop could be dug out). Because the process is instantaneous, there is no chance for anyone else to interfere by digging out the dead drop.

Comment: In this case, once the future receives the algorithm and its location, they will immediately trigger it, destroying everyone in the present.

Comment: If it was instant, he could just put it on the floor in front of the Rockefeller Centre. It needs to be hidden to stop people from grabbing it during the intervening x years. The item still needs to travel the long way round, even if it's instant *from the perspective of the person dropping it*

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150941/discussion-on-answer-by-galacticninja-why-is-this-act-supposed-to-be-a-final-suc); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.